# One or multiple SpriteKit texture atlases?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

So, say I want to create SKNodes with textures from a texture atlas. Every node will be built from multiple parts layered on top of each other, some of which will never change, some will. There will be many nodes, some of which will be created from the same set of parts, and others will be made from different sets of parts.

Instead of keeping all the images in the project separately, I want to create a texture atlas, but I've never used one before. What is the best setup for this? Here are the things I could come up with:
1. Throw all of it in one texture atlas
2. All changing parts in one atlas, static parts not in an atlas
3. All parts for one "type" of node in one atlas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all sprites used in the same scene(s) in the same atlas. If you don't expect high texture memory usage (ie all textures combined fit into 3-4 atlases sized 4096x4096) you need not consider splitting atlases, so a single atlas is perfectly fine.

Static/dynamic and grouping by "type" (however defined) should not be a consideration at all.